# Android Sensor Rotation Angle

Tags: java, android, rotation, sensors

I'm trying to detect the y-axis rotation angle (forward-backward tilt when holding in landscape) but I'm obviously doing thins wrong as the onSensorChanged event never gets triggered

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this.mSensorEventListener, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME); 
}

...

private SensorEventListener mSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float aX = event.values[1];
        float aY = event.values[2];

        double angle = aY * (Math.PI / 180);
        btnStop.setText(Double.toString(angle));
};
```

Comment: when you will shaking the device then it will call automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device probably does not have `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR`

Comment: that would seem rather strange for a Samsung Galaxy Tab, not?

Comment: but I guess you're right. I tested the code with TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and it did work...

Comment: Most devices still do not have gyros.

Comment: do you think it would be possible to use the tablet as a steering wheel and find out the angles without a gyro?

Comment: Yes you can use TYPE GRAVITY and type magnetic field to get the orientation of the tablet

Comment: I understand that I could use that to find x-axis rotation as it's like a compas but y-axis rotation angle, wouldn't that be impossible with these?

Comment: With y axis you need only type accelerometer. I will give you a link to one of my answer about an hour from now. I am typing from my phone, it is hard to look up my answer

Comment: The link is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709918/android-determining-the-angle-of-tilt-using-only-accelerometers